# Add space to toolbar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, toolbar, xib, uibarbuttonitem

I am new to iPhone,

I have added a toolbar in my `.xib` file and then added 5 `BarbuttonItem` to the toolbar,

**see snapshot:** [image: 1]
you can see bar buttons on toolbar, but there is no spaces between them.. what i want is.. there should be sufficient space between all button like `search bar` to placed at extreme right, `a` and `A` should be in the middle of tool bar.

when i try to drag `search bar` at extreme right it drags properly but on living of mouse click `search bar` again comes to it's original position.

**How to solve this ?**

***Any help will be appriciated.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Objects` panel there are two `UIBarButtonItem` subclasses named `Fixed Space Bar Button Item` and `Flexible Space Bar Button Item`. You need to use those two to adjust your spaces.